# Reconstruct Ant build in Maven but being open for change

Tags: java, maven, ant

We have a lot of `war` projects that need to be converted from Ant to Maven. In Ant, the dependencies are given in a nontransitive way.

Now it is required to get the exact same list of dependencies (including versions) in the converted Maven project. This is done to avoid excessive manual testing.

My first idea is to put *-excludes into all dependencies so that transitivity is ruled out completely. But on the other hand, I want to make it as easy as possible to convert these strange Maven projects (step by step) to real Maven projects.

Therefore I would like to find a "not too invasive" method of reproducing an exact list of dependencies.

Comment: By `nontransitve way` you mean explicit all dependencies given?

Comment: yes, all dependencies are listed explicitly. As this list is generated manually, it is most likely different from the one Maven would produce.

Comment: In the first step you can do that in Maven as well...which should in the end give the same result. Comparing the war file...afterwards you can step by step introduce transitive dependencies.

Comment: @khmarbaise You mean I should put exludes into all dependencies to avoid transitivity?